# Getting error while downloading DOM object as PDF using JSPDF

Tags: html, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm just downloading a `<div>` using `jspdf`, it is showing:

> 'Supplied data is not a JPEG'

I used a code that I got from one of Stack Overflow answers. It is working fine there.

I am attaching [link of jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/74gtwghw) where it is working fine but it is not working in my code.

Here is my code:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('b'), function() {
  pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```